# Mimicking Smart folders

Tags: macos, directory

I am new to mac programming. I have a small task to do. 
I  need to watch for file creation events in a folder, intercept them, and create symbolic links instead of a copy.

ANy idea if there is any source code to do so or any api i should use?

Answer (score 1):

The traditional solution on OS X is to use something called [Folder Actions](http://www.tuaw.com/2009/02/16/applescript-exploring-the-power-of-folder-actions-part-i/) which allows you to associate `AppleScripts` with particular folders and actions.  In more recent releases of OS X, Folder Actions are implemented under the covers by using [launchd](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20080423051638134) QueueDirectories and/or WatchPaths; it may be simpler to implement them directly.  Also see the `launchd` and `launchd.plist` man pages.